# what are some intermediate level probability textbook that is much more advance than Degroot's "Probability and Statistics"

Tags: probability

what are some intermediate level probability textbook that is much more advance than Degroot's  "Probability and Statistics" but are able to be understood by advanced undergraduate and beginning graduate students but also more than 350 pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely check out *Probability Theory and Stochastic Processes with Applications* by Oliver Knill. This is available on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8189938401) and also as a preliminary [manuscript](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math144_1994/probability.pdf). It makes use of measure theory which is developed in the book.

Comment: Nice, I like it.